# shortening method/variable names?

Tags: java, coding-style

Is it considered bad style to use long, but descriptive method names such as "adjacentLocationsByState()" and if so, would it be better to shorten it to something like "adjLocByState" which is definitely shorter, but also less readable in my opinion

Comment: Use the longer one.. Its more descriptive... If you want to go for the shorter one, you might as well use albs...There's no difference between - "Variable name makes little sense" and "variable name makes no sense"

Comment: Which would you rather encounter if you were reading a source file you were not familiar with?

Comment: Prefer elaboration over cleverness when naming things in code.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it asks for opinions and invites discussion.

Comment: BTW the best choice is a *short, descriptive name*. For example, I find Objective C code almost impenetrable precisely due to the long names which accumulate into walls of text, syntax and logic flow completely drowned out by sheer tons of alpha characters.

Answer (score 11):

Don't make me think.

When I read your code, if I have to stop and think about what the method name might mean, it usually means that the method name is wrong. Longer method names are preferable when it adds useful context to the method.

Comment: +1 for - " When I read your code, if I have to stop and think about what the method name might mean, it usually means that the method name is wrong."

Answer (score 3):

There are two rules I basically follow when writing code:

- Must be readable as a normal text to which a human eye got used from books and mass media (so `adjLocByState` is *not* the case)
- Maximize brevity, utilize programming techniques - code conventions and default states. These could be applied when some of the terms start appear to repeat too often.

So, adjacentLocationsByState() reads perfectly fine, but it could be shortened to just:

`adjacentLocations()`

which by default would return locations by their state and `adjacentLocations(STATE)` or chaining with [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) technique which allows more options for having the criteria: `adjacentLocations().by(STATE)`. STATE here is a member of an enum LocationCriteria.

So in the end of the day it could look like:

- `adjacentLocations()`
- `adjacentLocations().by(STATE)`
- `adjacentLocations(STATE)`

Of course, there is a time sacrifice which is spent on coding the 2nd and the 3rd forms.

Comment: Programmers are not humans, mass media standards don't apply :)) But seriously, the most readable code uses catchy *mnemonics* instead of complete phrases. Also, most local variable names are just placeholders and can be one or two letters long.

Comment: Take mathematics as an example---there's a field which has worked on notation for two millenia.

Comment: Well, yeah, I can understand `def` or `fun` from maths as I have maths background. And for many cases having shorts terms like `var` or `obj` would work pretty well, I often use these in my projects. This looks more like a domain-specific terminology or abbreviations which 'normal humans' use - i.e. DNA or CIA -everyone knows what these mean.

Comment: I also implied mathematics' use of single letters for variable names. For example `splitOnSpace(String s)` is perfectly readable for me.

Comment: ... business logic I believe should be as close as possible to the regular text and avoid being cryptic for a new team member. Too many repetitions look unnatural - this what you usually normally get, some sort of code entropy. So there are techniques for this which can be used to make a program text look more human-readable - like conventions or default states.

Comment: The perfect balance between destriptiveness and brevity is hard to strike---that's why naming is such a high art :) The choice of names is one of the most telling factors by which to assess the experience of the author.

Comment: Yes, I also think that when you start thinking of readability, simplicity, taking small steps, etc programming becomes more of an art. :)

Comment: Absolutely... otherwise we would have gotten tired of it a long time ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Longer version is more readable and the the code is self documenting. So a good method name = method responsibility. Adj can be understand as adjust or adjacent, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind: Code is read 10 times more than it is written.!

You really write code that will often be read again and again. The more meaningful your names are, the more understandable is the code.

You are declaring classes, fields, methods, variables, and many more. You are thinking about them, you are developping a well-defined structure. All the time, you make hard decisions. The names that you give to your entities (classes, fields, ...) reflect all your thoughts on that. They reflect the intention of your code.

Conclusion: Names are the most important properties of your code. So, you always should think deeply about the names you give to your variables, methods, and so on. And you always should not abbreviate them in what way ever.

Comment: I agree. I came to a new codebase in the last month and was reading variables with names like "rep". I assumed it meant "repetition" but it turned out it meant "report". It would have been much better for the original author to add those extra three letters and avoid the confusion!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. And the underlying reason for the variable named 'rep' is? The author didn't think about other readers of his code (other than himself). He maybe assumed, that only he will read it again. And this is always a wrong assumption; even at home. (Not to say, that my own code is hard to read for myself several months later, if it contains bad-named variables.)

Comment: Couldn't agree more! It applies to comments too - when working on my own projects, I comment everything as much for the benefit of ConfusedFutureMe as I do for the benefit of HypotheticalFutureCodeveloper.

Answer (score -1):

Its part of Documentation.

Usually everybody like to write Code in two phases before commit:

1. Implementation
2. Documentation

By example (phase 1):

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = ...
List a : ob.getSOE();
for(Object a: b){
   oos.writeObject(a);
}
```

Then phase 2:

```
ObjectOutputStream stackOverflowElementOuputStream = ...
List stackOverflowElements : ob.getStackOverflowElement();
for(Object currentStackOverflowElement: stackOverflowElements){
   stackOverflowElementOuputStream.writeObject(currentStackOverflowElement);
}
```

Comment: I find your second example almost as unreadable as the first one, just for different reasons. You have actually pointed out two routes to bad choice of name.